# setSemanticContentAttribute: not working in tvOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, tvos, apple-tv, tvos10

In my application i'm setting layout direction to Right to Left, my application works fine on tvOS 9, but when i run my application on tvOS 10 it runs in Left to Right layout direction.It looks like OS is ignoring setSemanticContentAttribute. I am using following code.

```
if(IOS9) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
    if ([[[UIView alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
        [[UILabel appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
        [[UITableView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
        [[UICollectionView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
        [[UIButton appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
    }
}else{
    if ([[[UIView alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value forceRightToLeft to the property semanticContentAttribute in tvOS does not have any effect. The views are anyway added from left to right.

This is a bug in tvOS https://openradar.appspot.com/31138095